# App crashes when opened from TestFlight but works fine otherwise

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, crash

I am facing some weird issue, my app crashes when I click on `OPEN` button in `TestFlight` but when I open the installed version of the app from the Home screen, it works fine. When I run the program directly on the device from `Xcode` it also works fine.

Comment: "from manu" means?

Comment: @Larme where all apps are available (Dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that your app build from Release mode. If your app build from debug mode then it may crash.

Comment: i did but facing same problem.

Comment: I have build app with release mode, still same issue.